# How to connect to CalDav calendar via iCal4j?

Tags: java, caldav, ical4j

I have a self-hosted CalDav calendar (**DaviCal**). Also, I have a Spring application, and I want to manage this calendar from my application (e.g. create events, users, scheduling).
I have found a CalDAV library - **iCal4j**, but I cannot find any good documentation on how to use it.
I need at least to connect to my calendar server. How to do it?
Thanks in advance!

(p.s. I know, that there is another library - **caldav4j** but it seems to me that it has no more supported.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ical4j-connector` subproject of ical4j is intended to support CalDAV connectivity.

https://github.com/ical4j/ical4j-connector

Admittedly it hasn't had much attention lately but you may want to look at the unit tests for examples on how to use it:

https://github.com/ical4j/ical4j-connector/blob/develop/src/test/groovy/net/fortuna/ical4j/connector/dav/ChandlerHubSpec.groovy

Bug reports and general issues are welcome in the Github issues section.

Comment: Thanks! Can you advise any sources with good examples of how to work with iCal4j (create calendars, scheduling, etc.)? Because on the original GitHub's repo, an example section is empty.

Comment: @IhorBiedin Did you already find good sources or examples? I'm struggeling with the same problem.